# Python - Quick way to get specific content from CSV

Tags: python, csv

What's the optimal way to get the following from CSV like this:

```
student_id,521,597,624,100
1,99,73,97,98
2,98,71,70,99
```

1. How I can get the exercise numbers (the top row excluding the student_id string)
2. How I can get only the grades (99,73,97,98,98,71,70,99)?

This is what I tried so far:

```
def read_students(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            exercise_data = list(csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=','))

        students = []
        exercises = []
        grades = []

        i = 0
        for column in exercise_data:
            if column[0] != "student_id":
                students.append(column[0])
        return exercises, students, grades

    except IOError as exc:
        return exc
```

Not sure how to get the `exercises` and `grades` - the `students` work.

expected output:

```
>>> exercises, students_ids, grades = read_students('example.csv')
>>> print('Total exercises, ids, grades:', exercises.shape[0], students_ids.shape[0],
grades.size)
Total exercises, ids, grades: 2 4 8
```

Comment: If you're allowed/ok with using external libraries, you should really, really look into `pandas`. They have a way to load CSVs quickly and efficiently and you then have a lot of flexibility as to how to manipulate the data

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pandas lib for file handling

```
import pandas

excel_data_df = pandas.read_csv(file, header=None )
stuid = excel_data_df.iloc[1:,0]
mark1 = excel_data_df.iloc[0:,1]
mark2 =  excel_data_df.iloc[0:,2]
print(mark1)
```

you can get any data using the variable

Comment: I'm not sure OP wants to skip the entire first row

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment above about what else you could look into for reading CSVs (`pandas` is especially nice for larger files)

But if you want a barebones Python solution to your question, here's my take at it:

```py
def read_students(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            exercise_data = [line.split(",") for line in f.readlines()]
        
        students = []
        exercises = list(map( int, exercise_data[0][1:]))
        grades = []

        for line in exercise_data[1:]:
            grades = grades + list(map(int, line[1:]))
            students.append(int(line[0]))

        return students, exercises, grades

        # I don't know what students does, but exercises and grades return what I think you're asking for

    except IOError as exc:
        return exc
```

I haven't run this myself, but this should give an idea.

Comment: Error when running: `exercise_data = list(map(int, [line.split(",") for line in f.readlines()]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: Another one `TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.`

Comment: Still, `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'student_id'` . I think you better run it

Comment: Why move away from the `csv` module?  It handles edge conditions like fields that include the delimiter and parsing quoted fields.

Comment: not tryna say csv is bad mate, just giving a bare bones solution. Edited now, works locally